# Passing javascript object property

Tags: javascript

How do you go about passing an objects properties in the follwoing situation:

```
ObjectTest = function()
{
    this.var1= "3";    
    this.var2= "";
}
```

and the call

```
    ObjectTest .prototype.allFriends = function() {

        function bindEvents() {
             //pass var1 here
        }
   }
```

Is there a way to pass the ObjectTest properties without passing them as properties of the bindEvents(). I'd prefer a global solution if at all possible

Answer (score 2):

```
ObjectTest.prototype.allFriends = function() {
    do_smth_with(this.var1);
}
```

Beware, though, that you create a new `ObjectTest` by calling `new ObjectTest()`; without the `new` keyword it will not work.

**EDIT:** It will *still* work, because of the inner function will inherit the outer function's (`allFriends`) [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)):

```
ObjectTest .prototype.allFriends = function() {
    function bindEvents() {
         console.log(this.var1);
    }
}
```

If it **still** doesn't work for you, use a reference to the parent's `this`:

```
ObjectTest .prototype.allFriends = function() {
    var parent = this;
    function bindEvents() {
         console.log(parent.var1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the same code in the prototype of allFriends as you used in the constructor:

```
ObjectTest = function()
{
    this.var1= "3";    
    this.var2= "";
}

ObjectTest.prototype.allFriends = function() {
    alert(this.var1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the same: this.var1 - run this:

```
ObjectTest = function() {
    this.var1 = 3;    
    this.var2 = "";
};

ObjectTest.prototype.allFriends = function() {
    alert(this.var1);
};

x = new ObjectTest();
x.allFriends();
```

Or see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9XYZU/